# Express regex router params

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying out regex options in  router to handle multiple path  as mentioned below along with the param i'm expecting.
How can i retrieve the param from the url, i tried `req.params[0]` it was returning `g`.

https://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/path1/image.png -- 'path1/image.png'
   https://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/image.png -- 'image.png'
   https://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/image_1.png -- 'image_1.png'

```
app.get(/^\/folder1\/folder2\/folder3\/(.)*$/, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get(/^.*\/([^\/]+)$/, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params[0]);
});
```

Comment: Above solution is intercepting most of the call, for me path till folder3 is going to be static  and rest is going to be dynamic `https://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/`

Comment: Try this regexp you probably have to fine tune the {3}:
/^((\/[^\/]+){3})(.+)$/

Comment: I have tried  below


`app.get('/folder1/folder2/folder3/((\\d*))', function(req, res){
        console.log( req.params[0] );
        res.json({name:req.params[0]});
    });`

But it only worked for
https://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/path1/34343sd.png

not for 
https://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/path1/sdsd.png

I want to allow any character

Comment: This one seems to work for my scenario, still testing it out.
` app.get('/folder1/folder2/folder3/((\\w*))', function(req, res){
        
    })`